# .NET Core 6 Pull Down Menu Selection to Group through View Model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am having partial success searching / grouping data through a viewmodel:

**Partial Success**:

URL Value

If I search on "B"

https://localhost:7207/Class01Name/Index2?String02NameSelected=**B**&SearchString=

**Problem:**

Not filtering data...simply changes pull down menu back to "All," displaying all data.  Data not filtered.

**Question:
**
What in the code has to be changed to have the data filtered successfully?

Question is based on Tutorial at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; // Date Format

namespace Project01Name.Models
{
    public class Class01Name
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? String01Name { get; set; }

        public string? String02Name { get; set; }

        public int? Int01Name { get; set; }

        public bool? Bool01Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? DateTime01Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**
View Model
**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Project01Name.Models.ViewModelsName
{
    public class SearchByGroupName
    {
        public List<Class01Name>? Class01NameList { get; set; }                // A list of movies.
        public SelectList? String02NameSelection { get; set; }                 // A SelectList containing the list of genres. This allows the user to select a genre from the list.
        public string? String02NameSelected { get; set; }                      // MovieGenre, which contains the selected genre.
        public string? SearchString { get; set; }                              // SearchString, which contains the text users enter in the search text box.
    }
}
```

**Controller Action Method**

```
       // GET: String01Names
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index2(string class01NameGroup, string searchString)
        {
            // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
            IQueryable<string> string02NameQuery = from m in _context.Class01Name
                                            orderby m.String02Name
                                            select m.String02Name;

            var selectVariable = from m in _context.Class01Name
                                            select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                selectVariable = selectVariable.Where(s => s.String01Name!.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(class01NameGroup))
            {
                selectVariable = selectVariable.Where(x => x.String02Name == class01NameGroup);
            }

            var string02NameVM = new SearchByGroupName
            {
                String02NameSelection = new SelectList(await string02NameQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                Class01NameList = await selectVariable.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(string02NameVM);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model Project01Name.Models.ViewModelsName.SearchByGroupName

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-action="Index2" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <select asp-for="String02NameSelected" asp-items="Model.String02NameSelection"> <option value="">All</option></select>
            Title: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />

            @*<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a> *@
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].String01Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].String02Name)
            </th>
                <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].Int01Name)       
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].DateTime01Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Class01NameList)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.String01Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.String02Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Int01Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTime01Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Partial Success**:

URL Value

If I search on "B"

https://localhost:7207/Class01Name/Index2?String02NameSelected=**B**&SearchString=

**Problem:**

Not filtering data...simply changes pull down menu back to "All," displaying all data.  Data not filtered.

**Question:
**
What in the code has to be changed to have the data filtered successfully?

Question is based on Tutorial at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

> Not filtering data...simply changes pull down menu back to "All,"
> displaying all data. Data not filtered.
> **Question: ** What in the code has to be changed to have the data filtered successfully?

Well, seems you wanted to implement searching functionality in way, so that you can filter with the dropdown and search box and finally if you select `All` as dropdown value you want to load all the list without any filter and shorting means the full list which comes at first view.

If so, you need to use javascript for your dropdown change event as `cshtml` doesn't deal with change event. In addition, as you are using `asp.net core MVC` which would return `HTML View` altough, we need json data for `Ajax` reponse but we are would bee  getting `HTML View`. So `Ajax success Function` will through an error where we would use filter with `All` parameter.

**Modification Required:**

Javascript:

```cs
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#allId").change(function () {
                alert("Click");
                var allId = $('#allId').val();
                console.log(allId);

                if (allId == "All") {
                    alert("Alert");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:5094/Search/Index2',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { String02NameSelected: "All", searchString: "" },
                        success: function (response) {
                        },
                        error: function () {
                              window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index2", "Search")?String02NameSelected=All&SearchString=";
                        }
                    });

                }


            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:**
As you can see, in success function we are doing nothing, because it will always throuh an error because we are not returning json. Thus, we will work in error section. `indow.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index2", "Search")?String02NameSelected=All&SearchString=";`. Here, for your understanding, we will call this function when we select `All` as our dropdown value in that scenario, we will pass `All` and nothing , nothing will convert into `null` and all will be our search key.

Modify Your Existing View:

In your existing view, replace blow dropdown code snippet , means the `select items`

```cs
<select asp-for="String02NameSelected" id="allId" asp-items="Model.String02NameSelection"> <option value="All">All</option></select>
```

**Note:** If you notice I hav introduced a id `id="allId"` which will be using on dropdown change event.

Controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index2(string String02NameSelected, string searchString)
        {


            if (String02NameSelected == "All" && searchString == null)
            {
             
                var dataWithoutfileter = new SearchByGroupName();
                dataWithoutfileter.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");
                dataWithoutfileter.Class01NameList = listOfClass01Name;
                return View(dataWithoutfileter);
            }

         
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(String02NameSelected) && String02NameSelected !="All")
            {
                var objOfClass = new SearchByGroupName();
                var string02NameQuery = listOfClass01Name.Where(m => m.String01Name.ToLower().Contains(String02NameSelected.ToLower()) || m.String02Name.ToLower().Contains(String02NameSelected.ToLower()));
                objOfClass.Class01NameList = string02NameQuery.ToList();

                objOfClass.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");


                return View(objOfClass);
            }


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                var objOfClass = new SearchByGroupName();
                var string02NameQuery = listOfClass01Name.Where(m => m.String01Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) || m.String02Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
                objOfClass.Class01NameList = string02NameQuery.ToList();

                objOfClass.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");


                return View(objOfClass);
            }

            //First loading
            var objSearchByGroupName = new SearchByGroupName();
            objSearchByGroupName.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");
            objSearchByGroupName.Class01NameList = listOfClass01Name;
            return View(objSearchByGroupName);


           
        }
    }
```

**Complete Demo:**

Full Controller With Seed Model Class Value:

```cs
public class SearchController : Controller
    {
        public static List<Class01Name> listOfClass01Name = new List<Class01Name>()
        {
            new Class01Name() { Id =101, String01Name ="Titanic",String02Name = "Romantic", Int01Name =01, Bool01Name = false, DateTime01Name = new DateTime(2023-01-15) },
            new Class01Name() { Id =102, String01Name ="Forest gump",String02Name = "Motivational", Int01Name =02, Bool01Name = true, DateTime01Name = new DateTime(2023-01-12) },
            new Class01Name() { Id =103, String01Name ="Spider Man",String02Name = "Action", Int01Name =03, Bool01Name = false, DateTime01Name = new DateTime(2023-01-10) },
            new Class01Name() { Id =104, String01Name ="Harry Potter",String02Name = "Suspense", Int01Name =04, Bool01Name = true, DateTime01Name = new DateTime(2023-01-13)},

        };

        public  List<SelectListItem> String02NameSelectionList = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Motivational", Value = "Motivational" },
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Romantic", Value = "Romantic" },
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "Action" },
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "Comedy" }
        };

       

public async Task<IActionResult> Index2(string String02NameSelected, string searchString)
        {


            if (String02NameSelected == "All" && searchString == null)
            {
             
                var dataWithoutfileter = new SearchByGroupName();
                dataWithoutfileter.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");
                dataWithoutfileter.Class01NameList = listOfClass01Name;
                return View(dataWithoutfileter);
            }

         
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(String02NameSelected) && String02NameSelected !="All")
            {
                var objOfClass = new SearchByGroupName();
                var string02NameQuery = listOfClass01Name.Where(m => m.String01Name.ToLower().Contains(String02NameSelected.ToLower()) || m.String02Name.ToLower().Contains(String02NameSelected.ToLower()));
                objOfClass.Class01NameList = string02NameQuery.ToList();

                objOfClass.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");


                return View(objOfClass);
            }


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                var objOfClass = new SearchByGroupName();
                var string02NameQuery = listOfClass01Name.Where(m => m.String01Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) || m.String02Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
                objOfClass.Class01NameList = string02NameQuery.ToList();

                objOfClass.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");


                return View(objOfClass);
            }

            //First loading
            var objSearchByGroupName = new SearchByGroupName();
            objSearchByGroupName.String02NameSelection = new SelectList(String02NameSelectionList, "Text", "Value");
            objSearchByGroupName.Class01NameList = listOfClass01Name;
            return View(objSearchByGroupName);


           
        }
    }
```

Full View:

```cs
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Controllers.SearchByGroupName

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}



<form asp-action="Index2" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <select asp-for="String02NameSelected" id="allId" asp-items="Model.String02NameSelection"> <option value="All">All</option></select>
            Title: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
            <input type="submit" name="searchString" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].String01Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].String02Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].Int01Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class01NameList[0].DateTime01Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Class01NameList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.String01Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.String02Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Int01Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTime01Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#allId").change(function () {
                alert("Click");
                var allId = $('#allId').val();
                console.log(allId);

                if (allId == "All") {
                    alert("Alert");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:5094/Search/Index2',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { String02NameSelected: "All", searchString: "" },
                        success: function (response) {
                        },
                        error: function () {
                              window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index2", "Search")?String02NameSelected=All&SearchString=";
                        }
                    });

                }


            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]